# Make Facebook post in multiple languages using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

I'm developing a script that will create a Facebook post on our FB page for each blog post that we publish on our website. Since our blog posts are translated into multiple languages, I'd like to take advantage of multi-language posts on Facebook. I know how to create those posts on the FB website (https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151544094843003), but I cannot find a way to do this with the API.

This is how I create a regular post:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/546349135390552/feed?message=Message&link=www.abc.de
```

I've also found out how to localize Open Graph objects (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/), but a post in a feed is not an Open Graph object I think.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not possible as of now. The most you could do is use the targeting options.

Comment: This is a great idea, I'll take a look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looks like there is no way for now (or I am missing something):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/page/feed
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/

I've just found this and pretty curious how Facebook is holding that back. Well, I can understand the reason actually, but not sure why community is not forcing this. Facebook describe themselves as open minded and free for every opinion, free from censorship, but on practice it's only when convenient for the social network.

Their publishing tools are terrible and as a publisher I want posts to be published in one click from one endpoint rather that opening each social network and spend a lot of time of manual work. A bit of coding can save tons of time for publishers, but NO!

P.S. Let's push Facebook to open this kind of API finally. It's 2020 already!

Comment: Did you find any solution since then? It's like they want to have a page for each country :'(

Comment: Even writing post in multilingual isn't possible since a few months.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling they decided to specifically bury that feature in favour (maybe because not many used it) of their translation feature. Which is so lame in a lot of cases, especially for specific publishing (like we did for music zine — genres, band names, album titles etc). So in the end we just stick with English for Facebook, but that went much worse in audience.

Comment: @Dymtro yeah but I found out they're not translating things automatically now, I don't understand their logic on this... I have customers that complain about non translated text. Their documentation states it's still possible to make multilingual posts, there's a parameters section of it on the parameters UI, but there's no actual UI to do that once you post a publication... I don't understand the logic of throwing out a good feature...

Comment: @MicaëlFélix wow, you're right, don't see any options to add Post translation now. But that was possible some time ago! (Not sure when last time though). Checked now with both Facebook and Meta editors to create a post. At first I thought maybe you need to turn on "multiple locales" switch somewhere in Page settings. They still exist but seem to do nothing?

Comment: Check: Page / General:
- `Post in Multiple Languages`
- `Translate Automatically`

Closer to the bottom of the list on that page.

Comment: I've already seen this, doesn't seem to change anything. I tried to disable & re-enable just in case. Anyway I prefered the old UI to post messages in multiple languages, as now we're not even capable to set a specific text for a specific language either in API or UI mode :'(